# What's the formula for referring cell values from every column in a row from Sheet 'A' to every 'nth' column in a row in Sheet'B'?

Tags: copy

Cell values in Sheet'A' :

A1 - 1

B1 - 2

C1 - 3

D1 - 4

E1 - 5

F1 - 6

G1 - 7

H1 - 8

I1 - 9

J1 - 10

K1 - 11

L1 - 12

M1 - 13

N1 - 14

O1 - 15

P1 - 16

Q1 - 17

And so on...

Values required to copy in Sheet"B"

1 in D1 (4th column-Sheet"B")

2 in in H1(8th column-Sheet"B"))

3 in L1 (12th column-Sheet"B"))

And so on...

Comment: Use `Range(...).Offset()` in VBA.